# Finding gradient got error: Error in x[3] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, gradient

I want to find gradient of the function, where `o` is from 1:15. My code is:

```
  g<-function(x){
  j<-(x[1]+x[2]*((1-exp(-o/x[3]))/(o/x[3]))+
                x[4]*((1-exp(-o/x[3]))/(o/x[3])-exp(-(o/x[3])))+ 
                x[5]*((1-exp(-o/x[6]))/(o/x[6])-exp(-(o/x[6]))))
  }
gradient(g)
```

But I got error:

```
Error in x[3] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Where does the `gradient` function come from? It does not seem to be defined in base R. Also how is `o` defined?

Comment: @MrFlick 'o' is time, function is Svenson function, see:( https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/YieldCurve/versions/4.1/topics/Svensson), where o goes from 1:15. Can you help me how to find gradient of this function? I want to use it for lbfgs function

Comment: Even after installing an loading the cited package and setting `o <- 1:15` I still get `Error in gradient(g) : could not find function "gradient"`. Do you realize that there are limited symbolic differentiation capabilies in R? See `?D`

Comment: After looking at your 4 prior related questions  and searching for a package that has a `gradient` function and reviewing the cited page further, I suspect this is not the right place to pose this series of question. Rather consider the "Quantitative Finance" stackexchange forum might be more appropriate. There you might expect to find an audience that can fill in the huge gaps in you problem description. You should of course describe the background for your problem . I'm guessing that it is a finance problem and you are trying to answer some question about interest rates and bond pricing.

Comment: @IRTFM I just want to use lbfgs and need find gradient of function, where `x` is vector of variables and `o` goes from 1:15. I do not have gaps in anything financial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function has no global minimum. This is because x[1] can be set to -infinity. So, I suspect there is something not right about this function that you're trying to minimize.

In case you still care, the gradient is something like the following. But I'm not 100% sure it's correct. In any case, it's useless in lbfgs, optim, or gradient descent.

```
grad=function(x) {
  a=x[1]; b=x[2]; c=x[3]; f=x[4]; g=x[5]; h=x[6]
  p=1
  q=c*(1-exp(-o/c))/o
  r=exp(-o/c)*((f+b)*c^2*exp(o/c)+(-f-b)*c^2+(-f-b)*o*c-f*o^2)/o/c^2
  s=c*(1-exp(-o/c))/o-exp(-o/c)
  t=h*(1-exp(-o/h))/o-exp(-h/o)
  u=g*((1-exp(-o/h))/o-exp(-o/h)/h+exp(-h/o)/o)
  return(c(p,q,r,s,t,u))
}
```

Let f be the function (x-1)^2+y^2+5. This has a global minimum at 5 when x=1 and y=0. Agree? Just a 3-D parabolic bowl. We use three minimization methods, for each we expect the minimizing method to find a minimum at approximately (1,0) and the gradient will be the zero-vector at the minimum.

```
# function is (x-1)^2+y^2+5
func=function(x) {
  return((x[1]-1)^2+x[2]^2+5)
}
# gradient is (2(x-1), 2y)
grad=function(x) {
  return(c(2*(x[1]-1), 2*x[2]))
}

#Method 1: optim
op=optim(c(1,1), func, method="BFGS")
op$par
1.000000e+00 1.100231e-13 # about (1, 0)
grad(op$par)
0.000000e+00 2.200462e-13 # about (0, 0)

# Method 2: gradient descent
x=c(1,1)
for (i in 1:100000) {
  x=x-.01*grad(x)
}
x
1.000000e+00 1.185758e-322 # about (1, 0)
grad(x)
0.000000e+00 2.371515e-322 # about (0, 0)

# Method 3: lbfgs
l=lbfgs(func, grad, vars=c(1,1))
l$par
1 0 # exactly (1, 0)
grad(l$par)
0 0 # exactly (0, 0)
```